# Parsing array values to WooCommerce REST API

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to create a new product with multiple images using WooCommerce REST API

Here is the REST API syntax for images src: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

```
'images' => [
    [
        'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_front.jpg'
    ],
    [
        'src' => 'http://demo.woothemes.com/woocommerce/wp-content/uploads/sites/56/2013/06/T_2_back.jpg'
    ]
]
```

Now on PHP I have images URLs in an array `$images` like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61imqvdVv1L._SL1000_.jpg
    [1] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61CpVDq9iwL._SL1000_.jpg
    [2] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61IMXxbcfpL._SL1000_.jpg
    [3] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61HFUejnppL._SL1000_.jpg
    [4] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51whKF45l0L._SL1000_.jpg
    [5] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uPvXbo3IL._SL1000_.jpg
    [6] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61sNz9zDalL._SL1000_.jpg
    [7] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oytt8fP5L._SL1000_.jpg
    [8] => https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61Qarg%2BmjrL._SL1000_.jpg
)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to put `$images` array to the REST API but still stuck.

Any helps would be much appreciated!

Comment: So you need to format the second array like the first?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the best option. 
Here is the REST API docs for creating new product: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create a new array with index `images` like:

```
$yourImageArray = array(
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61imqvdVv1L._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61CpVDq9iwL._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61IMXxbcfpL._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61HFUejnppL._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51whKF45l0L._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51uPvXbo3IL._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61sNz9zDalL._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51oytt8fP5L._SL1000_.jpg',
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/61Qarg%2BmjrL._SL1000_.jpg'
);

$newArray = array();
foreach($yourImageArray as $key => $val){
    $newArray['images'][$key] = array('src'=>$val);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArray);
```

[DEMO](https://paiza.io/projects/X24jSdSe-cZNfap0TjpgfA)

Comment: Thanks man. I tried this but doesn't work:

 $data = [
    'name' => $product_name,
    'type' => 'simple',
    'regular_price' => $product_price,
    'sale_price' => $product_sale_price,
    'description' => $product_description,
    'categories' => [
   [
    'id' => $product_category
   ],
  ],
    $newArray
 ];

Comment: @AnthonyL.: that is the new story let me think aboutthis.

Comment: `print_r($data)` check whats wrong in your complete array. @AnthonyL.

Comment: I extract the image (the first array level) out, then added as 'images' => $newArray
and it worked. Thank you so much

Comment: @AnthonyL.: glad to help u